# Add custom http headers to chai requests

Tags: node.js, testing, request, chai

I am building an app using node.js and testing with mocha + chai. Is there a way I can add custom headers to my GET and POST chai requests?

For example, I want something like (semi-pseudocode):

```
chai.request(server)
  .get('/api/car/' + data.car_id)
  .headers({'some_custom_attribute':'some_value'})
  .end(function(err, res) {
    //do something
  });
```

And likewise with post:

```
chai.request(server)
  .post('/api/car/')
  .headers({'some_custom_attribute':'some_value'})
  .send({car_id: 'some_car_id'})
  .end(function(err, res) {
    //do something
  });
```

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use `set` function to set http headers:

```
chai.request(server)
  .get('/api/car/' + data.car_id)
  .set('some_custom_attribute', 'some_value')
  .end(function(err, res) {
    //do something
  });
```

[setting-up-requests](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http#setting-up-requests)

Comment: and how to add post variables along with headers?

Comment: @user269867 use `send` method for that.

Comment: can you please guide me for simpler method to add multiple headers in `chai.request` because In my scenario I have more than 10 headers

Comment: @NazirAhmed try something like that: `let headers = [{ name: 'h1', value: 'v1' }, /* OTHER HEADERS */]; let chain = chai.request.get(/*YOUR REQUEST*/); headers.forEach(headers, header => chain = chain.set(header.name, header.value)); chain.end(/* DO SOMETHING */);`

Comment: @alexmac Getting TypeError: chain.set is not a function

Comment: This is my code:   let chaiRequest = chai.request(app);  for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        chaiRequest.set(headers[ i ].key, headers[ i ].value)
      } return chaiRequest
        .post(url)
        .send(params)
        // .set(headers[ 0 ].key, headers[ 0 ].value)
        .then(res => {
          return res
        })

Comment: @alexmac How to set header for multiple request without using .set() all the time, since I dont want to repeat myself.

Comment: notice that `set('header', value)` must be called after the HTTP method (get, post, etc.)